# Where does MySQL store its database files on OS X?

Tags: mysql, mac-osx

As I would like to move those files from one server to another server, while the database is offline.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It [should be stored in](http://www.entropy.ch/software/macosx/mysql/): /usr/local/mysql/data

Comment: Just as a note, this is where it was stored when I installed MySQL using their actual GUI installer rather than via Homebrew. There are quite a lot of different ways of installing it!

Answer (score 26):

When you use mysql installed via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), you should find your database folders and files in `/usr/local/var/mysql`

Answer (score 2):

On macOS Monterey v. 12.6, mysql v. 8.0.31 - installed via with Homebrew 3.6.7 - keeps its databases under `/opt/homebrew/var/mysql`.

Answer (score 1):

OS X Server (at least v10.6) keeps the database in /var/mysql by default.  You can change this in Server Admin -> MySQL service -> Settings -> Database location (note that editing this field doesn't actually move the data, just changes where it's loaded from).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to my Mac right now, so can't say for certain. Why not simply search (from Terminal, not Spotlight) the file system for "mysql", as there will always be a table named mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the my.cnf file - should be in the /etc/ directory and then look for a line like:

datadir=/var/lib/mysql

The datadir is where mysql stores all the database files.

Autobyte

Answer (score 0):

If you've installed MySQL by running MAMP on the Mac, then the files are stored at `/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql`

For MAMP Pro, the files should be in `/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql`

Stack Overflow answer that addresses MAMP / Sequel Pro installations here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341897/where-does-sequel-pro-mamp-store-local-databases

Answer (score 0):

With respect to a Homebrew installed MySQL (in my case its v5.7 which is not the latest default of version 8) on Mac Catalina, the following applies (at least for a keg):

- The default config file is here:    /usr/local/etc/my.cnf
- The default loc for the db is here: /usr/local/var/mysql

When starting the server, you have some options to do it:

- Use the brew startup:  brew services start mysql
- Or, that's equivalent to: /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql

If you're using a specific version of mysql (in my case I'm using v5.7 and thus its a keg-only install), the service name is mysql@5.7 and the bin path is /usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7